# "Acceso denegado" al usar IIS local en VS 2019 con uso de DLL y conexión a servicio externo

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2019, vs

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web en VS 2019 con c# ASPNET y MVC, he implementado una DLL que nos proporcionaron para usarla, hasta ahora todo funciona correctamente al hacerlo desde la herramienta con el IIS Express, pero al querer implementarlo en una plataforma web con las mismas características en el proyecto pero haciendo uso del IIS local o montada directamente en mi IIS me arroja el error "Acceso denegado".

Ahora el error en sí no me da muchos detalles puesto que es generado al hacer uso de la DDL y no me da más información por lo que no puedo avanzar mucho.

Me gustaría saber si alguien tiene alguna pista de como proseguir puesto que he cambiado algunas configuraciones del IIS en mi máquina, agregado reglas de entrada pero no estoy muy familiarizada con las condiciones que se necesitan o que debería revisar para seguir avanzando.

Comment: Pueden ser que tengas que registrar tu dll en la cache.

Comment: Gracias @RamiroBarone, lo intenté pero no tuve éxito en registrarla, aunque ya encontré la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de hacer muchos cambios en la configuración de IIS me encontré con que era necesario establecer una cuenta de identificación para lograr acceder a los archivos que necesitaba.

Este sitio me dio la pista de cómo proseguir:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1749/access-denied-when-trying-to-connect-to-remote-iis-server-from-my-local-workst

Cree un grupo de aplicación en el servidor estableciendo la Identidad en la configuración avanzada mi cuenta administrador, aunque bastaría con alguna cuenta que tuviese acceso al archivo requerido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]